# how to list all the contents of a Plone site at a single click

Tags: plone

How do I list all the contents of a Plone site. It should show all the folders and subfolders with the contents all inclusive with various statistics like type, workflow state, creator, date created etc at a single shot in tabular form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Site map'  hyperlink in the site footer provides this information.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at how works the sitemap

Answer (score 1):

You could also [create a Topic/Collection](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/using-collections/adding-collections) with a criteria matching all content, and select the tabular view with all available metadata. Unfortunately, this won't tell anything about the hierarchy (like the sitemap does).